# Передать все email записи с базы mysql в Form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

имеется форма

```
<form action="" method="post" class="form">

<div <?=(!empty($errors['user_email']))? 'class="error_field"': '';?>>
    <label>Ваш e-mail адрес:</label>
    <input type="text" class = "text" name="user_email" value="<?=$validator->postdata('user_email');?>" />
</div> 

<div <?=(!empty($errors['subject']))? 'class="error_field"': '';?>>
    <label>Тема письма:</label>
    <input type="text" class = "text" name="subject" value="<?=$validator->postdata('subject');?>"/>
</div> 

<div class="area<?=(!empty($errors['text']))? ' error_field': '';?>">
    <label>Текст сообщения:</label>
    <textarea cols="40" class = "textarea" rows="5" name="text"><?=$validator->postdata('text');?></textarea>
</div> 

<div <?=(!empty($errors['keystring']))? 'class="error_field"': '';?>>
    <label class="captcha">Введите цифры изображенные на картинке:</label>
    <div class="capth_images"><?php require 'captcha.php';?></div>
    <input type="text" class = "text" name="keystring" value=""/>
</div> 

<div>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Отправить сообщение" />
</div>
```

Тут есть пункт `<input type="text" class = "text" name="user_email" value="<?=$validator->postdata('user_email');?>" />`

Подключился к базе и вывел список чтоб узнать кто там и что там.
[image: вывод с базы mysql]

Неделю мучаюсь, как мне запилить теперь туда эти почты автоматом

```
$to = array('mail@yandex.ru', 'mail1@yandex.ru);
```

Comment: Не понятно что случилось и что вы хотите. Поподробнее.

Comment: вы хотите отправить сообщение на все эти емейлы, которые присутствуют в базе или просто список емейлов отправить в сообщении?

Comment: Дмитриц, верно. Хочу отправлять письма

Comment: Дмитриц, верно. Хочу отправлять письма на эти почты